# PAM authentication problems

Tags: linux, ssh, arch-linux, pam, google-authenticator

I am trying to set up PAM authentication along side public key authentication in SSH inside of a LXD arch container. when i connect and give the proper code, i get this information in the journal on the server side:

```
Jan 31 21:04:41 arch sshd[2424]: PAM unable to resolve symbol: pam_sm_acct_mgmt
Jan 31 21:04:41 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: debug: start of google_authenticator for "root"
Jan 31 21:04:41 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: debug: Secret file permissions are 0400. Allowed permissions are 0600
Jan 31 21:04:41 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: debug: "/root/.google_authenticator" read
Jan 31 21:04:41 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: debug: shared secret in "/root/.google_authenticator" processed
Jan 31 21:04:41 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: debug: google_authenticator for host "10.145.176.1"
Jan 31 21:04:52 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: debug: no scratch code used from "/root/.google_authenticator"
Jan 31 21:04:52 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: Accepted google_authenticator for root
Jan 31 21:04:52 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: debug: "/root/.google_authenticator" written
Jan 31 21:04:52 arch sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2426]: debug: end of google_authenticator for "root". Result: Success
Jan 31 21:04:52 arch sshd[2424]: error: PAM: User account has expired for root from 10.145.176.1
Jan 31 21:04:52 arch sshd[2424]: fatal: monitor_read: unpermitted request 104
```

On the connecting side, after i input the correct code, it seems to connect and the connection instantly gets closed:

```
user@magician:~
 $ ssh root@10.145.176.228                                                                                 
(root@10.145.176.228) Verification code: 
Connection closed by 10.145.176.228 port 22
```

The same happens when i try connecting with a scratch code (the backup ones that libpam-google-authenticator gives) and the only difference in the journal is that the scratch code was used.

changed part of my `sshd_config`:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam 
PasswordAuthentication no 
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes 
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
 PermitRootLogin yes 
UsePAM yes
```

my `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
#%PAM-1.0 
# auth      include   system-remote-login 
# account   include   system-remote-login
# password  include   system-remote-login
# session   include   system-remote-login
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so debug 
account required pam_google_authenticator.so debug
```

The root account is not expired. output of `chage -l root`:

```
Last password change                                    : Sep 19, 2010
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : -1
Maximum number of days between password change          : -1
Number of days of warning before password expires       : -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'chage' output is only related to the result of pam_unix.so, but that is not the only module involved here – your PAM `account` session also has pam_google_authenticator.so listed as "required".

However, pam_google_authenticator.so does not have a handler for "account" functions (it only deals with "auth" stage), and configuring it for "account" will most likely result in a generic error being reported by default.

In other words, remove `account required pam_google_authenticator.so`, because it's not a user *authorization* module, only an authentication module.